# Eclipse ganymede startup error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.4, ganymede

I have an eclipse installation on an windows 7 64 bit machine.
Everytime I start the eclipse ganymede (by double clicking eclipse icon) I see this problem.
...See image...

[image: Eclipse ganymede startup error]

I see win32 in the image snapshot could this be a problem? I do not see any log files in the eclipse installation location.

eclipse.ini file:

```
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-vm
D:\DevProgs\Dumps\JVMS\win32-jdk1.6.0_23-b05\bin\java.exe
-framework
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.0.v20080605-1900.jar
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms150m
-Xmx512m
```

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks,
Ayusman

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are running the 64-bit Sun JVM. Eclipse runs against the Win32 windowing system system. Most of the time this is not a problem but you might want to install the 32-bit JDK and try running Eclipse against that.

Comment: I pointed my eclipse install to a 32 bit SDK and no luck... please look at my initial question above to see how my eclipse.ini file looked.

Answer (score 1):

You're using 32bit Eclipse on a 64bit platform. You need to [download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and use the 64bit Eclipse.

Comment: I went to this link: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/ganymede/sr2      and I do not see any 64bit windows package. is there any other link I can get 64 bit install?

Comment: Ganymede is 3 years old. Use Helios or Indigo. There's a link to Indigo SR1 64 bit in my answer.

Comment: I already have those setups. I had some old eclipse ganymede projects and that is when I encountered this problem. I am just curious on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Just reimport projects in Indigo?